Testing for significance where results are expressed as a ratio to an in group control
I originally asked this question in the biology stack exchange site, but realise that it might be more relevant here in the stats site:
I have a large dataset that represents a library of yeast deletion mutants and their growth under treatment from a compound. In the library alongside the mutants is a wild-type strain and I want to express each mutants response to treatment as a ratio to the WT response in order to highlight mutants that show abnormal sensitivity to the compound (hyper-sensitive or resistant) . So far I have settled on a formula to calculate the ratios but am struggling to think of a way to test for significance of results.
For example (not actual data, just for demonstration of data structure):

where I am calculating corrected ratio as:
((growth of mutant treated)/(growth of WT treated))/((growth of mutant at control)/(growth of WT at control))

i.e correcting the ratios with treatment to account for difference in growth at control condition
This then allows me to define sensitivity as corrected ratio<1 and resistance as >1
Is there a way to incorporate a simple statistical test into this to highlight ratios that show significant difference from the WT (where the ratio will always equate to 1)? I have replicates for each mutant and WT (typically N=4) so can easily calcutae SD/SEM etc.

A better way to approach this is to model all the growth rates in terms of  both Strain and Treatment via multiple linear regression. That provides information about both the difference of each Strain from WT in control conditions and the difference in response to Treatment. Given a pretty reasonable assumption, that will directly give you significance tests not only for your Corrected.Ratio values but also for strain differences from WT under control conditions. If you aren't already familiar with multiple linear regression, this is a good time to learn it.
The assumption is that it's OK to work in the log scale of Growth values instead of in their original scale. That could be OK (provided you don't have negative or 0 growth rates) if the error in determining a growth rate tends to be proportional to the magnitude of the rate. That makes regression in the log scale more likely to meet the assumptions of linear regression.
The ratios you want to evaluate are simple differences in the log scale, easy to handle and readily amenable to statistical analysis. Remember that the log of a ratio is the difference between the log of the numerator and the log of the denominator.
Call the wild-type control growth rate WT_C, the mutant control rate Mut_C, and the corresponding treated growth rates WT_T and Mut_T. Then the logs of your ratios are:
$$ \log (\text{Control.Ratio}) = \log (\text{Mut_C}) - \log (\text{WT_C})$$
$$ \log (\text{Treated.Ratio}) = \log (\text{Mut_T}) - \log (\text{WT_T})$$
$$ \log (\text{Corrected.Ratio}) = \log (\text{Mut_T}) - \log (\text{WT_T}) - \log (\text{Mut_C}) + \log (\text{WT_C})$$
Tests on both the Control.Ratio and the Corrected.Ratio values can come directly from a linear regression in this log scale.
Set up the data with one row per observation annotated with the outcome value Growth and with predictors Treatment (coded: control=0, treated=1) and Strain, in a data frame called yeastData. To simplify interpretation, set up the Strain values so that the reference level is WT. Then perform the following multiple regression model in R:
yeastModel <- lm(log(Growth) ~ Strain * Treatment, data = yeastData)

That model will provide:

an Intercept,let's call it $\beta_0$, equal to $\log (\text{WT_C})$, the estimate at reference conditions.
a coefficient for each other Strain representing its control difference in log growth rate from WT, or $\log (\text{Control.Ratio})$. Let's call that $\beta_{S}$. You can use that coefficient to test for the difference in control growth rate from WT.
a coefficient for Treatment representing the difference in log growth rate between Treated and Control for WT: $\log (\text{WT_T})-\log (\text{WT_C})$. That's the log of the treatment/control ratio for WT. Call it $\beta_T$.
an interaction coefficient, call it $\beta_{ST}$, for each other strain representing the difference between the log growth rate under treatment ($\log (\text{Mut_T})$) and what you would expect based on the combination of: the WT control log growth rate ($\beta_0$), the strain's difference at control from WT ($\beta_S$), and the treatment-associated difference for WT ($\beta_T$):

$$\beta_{ST}= \log (\text{Mut_T})-(\beta_0 +\beta_S +\beta_T) .$$
Substituting the interpretations of the $\beta$ coefficients above show that the interaction coefficient is equal to $\log (\text{Corrected.Ratio})$. If the assumptions of the linear model are met in the log-scale analysis, then the "significance" assessment you want comes directly from the interaction coefficient, as the p-value is reported for the difference from 0 in the log scale (i.e, from a ratio of 1 in the original scale).
If you want to go beyond these comparisons, for example to make comparisons among the strains, you can use post-modeling tools like those in the R emmeans package (also worth learning early on in your training).
There are some cautions here.
First, although these ratios seem simple initially, they aren't always the best descriptions of the underlying biology.
Second, as you have multiple strains you should consider a correction for multiple comparisons. In this type of situation you typically want to control for the false discovery rate.
Third, if the assumptions of linear regression don't hold adequately in the log scale, you will need to adapt the analysis appropriately. The main question is whether the residuals of observations around the model predictions have a reasonably constant variance independent of the predicted value. There are ways to proceed if they don't, but you should seek additional statistical expertise in that case.
Finally, remember that you are then modeling the mean of the log-growth values, not the logs of the mean growth values. There can be a substantial difference.
